# How to fix in executeSql "INSERT INTO error code: 0 "

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, cordova

I try to do an insert after the create but I do something wrong...
The CREATE work properly, but the insert don't work...

```
function createTableDB(tx) {
var data= "test";
var val1 = "testVal1";
var val2 = "testVal2";
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST');
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEST (id unique, data, scommesso, vincita)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TEST (data, scommesso, vincita) VALUES (?,?,?)' , [data, val1, val2]);
        }
```

I try also this and work:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO TEST (data scommesso, vincita) VALUES (?,?,?)', ["someText", "someText", "someText"]);
```

But I need to send the variable's value.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: First thing:  Unless you declare `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, then you must also specify the ID value.  It is not automatic in the case of your code.  Alternatively you can can exclude the `id` column and just rely on the automatic `rowid` column which is automatically populated.  If you are unsure or just to learn more, then start with [this page](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) and find more info in other docs on the same site.

Comment: @CPerkins It'll just be null in OP's case since he's not providing a value when inserting.

Comment: Ooooh. Your second insert is missing a comma. That's the one that shouldn't be working as a result.

Comment: @Shawn  Yes, thanks.  My mind was inserting "NOT NULL" in there... since most id values will have that.  I'll leave my original comment however since it still seems that this "id" column is missing important properties even if that's not the source of the error.